# How to tap specific cell in table UI Automation (Switft)

Tags: ios, swift, automation, ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

I'm attempting to write a test that selects a random cell from a table and then does assertion of the common elements that should be displayed for each selected element. I want to avoid tapping specific coordinates but i am almost completely new to both automation and programming and can't find any answers. I don't want complete code just some advice if that's even possible. Thanks!

Comment: I've put together a [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/) that could help with some other questions you're sure to have.

Answer (score 3):

Use the query for cells to work out how many there are and generate a random number from the count to access a random one.

```
let cells = XCUIApplication().tables.cells
let n = arc4random_uniform(cells.count)
let randomCell = cells.elementBountByIndex(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get random cell by something like

```
let cell = XCUIApplication().tables.cells.elementAtIndex(randomInt)
```